# Member object of another class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have two classes: Location and Adress. Adress contains a member named l1 which is of the type Location.

```
class Location
{
    double lat, lon;
    char *em;

    public:
        Location(int =0, int=0, const char* =NULL);
        ~Location();
        Location (const Location&);
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Location &);
};

class Adress
{
    char *des;
    Location l1;
    char *country;

    public:
        Adress(char *,Location &, char *);
        virtual ~Adress();
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Adress &);
};
```

**Adress constructor**:

```
Adress::Adress(char *des, Location &l1, char *country)
{
    if (des!=NULL)
    {
        this->des=new char [strlen (des)+1];
        strcpy (this->des, des);
    }
    if (country!=NULL)
    {
        this->country=new char [strlen (country)+1];
        strcpy (this->country, country);
    }

}
```

**Location constructor:**

```
Location::Location(int lat, int long, const char *em)
{
    this->lat=lat;
    this->lon=lon;
    if (emi!=NULL)
    {
        this->em=new char [strlen (em)+1];
        strcpy (this->em, em);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is when I call the constructor of the class Location in the main function for creating a new object to automatically call the constructor of the location class, something like: `Address ("desc", l1 (43.23, 32.12, "south"), "country")`. I have tried in many ways but none of them seems to work. Sorry for my mistakes, I'm a begginer.

Comment: What is Adresa(..) in your Adress class? Typo?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been "Adress". I've edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to pass temporary location object to Address constructor so your parameterized constructor definition should be changed to accept const Location& and here is sample code for what you want to achieve :

```
class Location
{
    double lat, lon;
char *em;

    public:
        Location(int =0, int=0, const char* =NULL);
        ~Location();
        Location (const Location&);
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Location &);



    protected:

    private:
};

class Adress

{
    char *des;
Location l1;
char *country;
    public:
        Adress(char *,const Location &, char *);
        virtual ~Adress();
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Adress &);

    protected:

    private:
};

Adress::Adress(char *des, const Location &l1, char *country)
{
    if (des!=NULL)
    {
        this->des=new char [strlen (des)+1];
        strcpy (this->des, des);
    }
    if (country!=NULL)
    {
        this->country=new char [strlen (country)+1];
        strcpy (this->country, country);
    }

}
Location::Location(int lat, int lon, const char *em)
{
    this->lat=lat;
    this->lon=lon;
    if (em!=NULL)
    {
        this->em=new char [strlen (em)+1];
        strcpy (this->em, em);
    }
}
int main()
{
    Adress ("desc", Location (43.23, 32.12, "south"), "country");
    return 0;
}
```

Also you cannot call class constructor with object name so l1 should be changed to class name i.e Location

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works. But I have another problem now. I'm trying to overload the << operator to dispaly the members of an Adress object. But when I try to : cout<<a1.l1.em (a1 is an object of Adress class) it says Location::em is private.  How do I resolve that?

Comment: much of the code here is unnecessary. read about [initializer list](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list), plus `new char`???

Answer (score 0):

Using `struct`, you can use [`brace-initialization`](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:braced-init-list), which follows the order of your variable declaration inside the struct.

```
struct Location
{
    double lat, lon;
    char *em;
};

struct Address
{
    char *des;
    Location l1;
    char *country;
};

Address address {"My address", Location{188.0, 188.0, "1 em"}, "USA"};
std::cout << address.l1.lat << ", " << address.l1.lon ; // 188.0, 188.0
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have to use classes.